# Right paddle not moving in pong game for unity

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

I am trying to allow the player, in a pong game, to control both paddles. However, for some reason only one paddle is controllable while the other simply does nothing. Here is an image of the paddle property bar.

[image]

And here is the code to the right most paddle that should be controlled with arrow keys.

```
    using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class PaddleRight : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public Vector3 playerPosR;
public float paddleSpeed = 1F;
public float yClamp;
void Start()
{


}

// Update is alled once per frame
void Update()
{

    float yPos = gameObject.transform.position.y + (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * paddleSpeed);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        playerPosR = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, Mathf.Clamp(yPos, -yClamp, yClamp), 0);
        print("right padddle trying to move");
    }

    gameObject.transform.position = playerPosR;
}
```

}

I can't seem to figure out anywhere why it won't move.. Please, any help would be awesome because I have checked everywhere at this point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the problem in a project and found that the only problem with it might be you forgetting that the `yClamp` is public and its set to 0 in the inspector. Make sure you set `yClamp` to whatever it should be instead of 0.

I would suggest moving the yPos assignment as well as setting the position inside the if statement as you arent changing those if the player isnt moving.

You can also change `gameObject.transform.position` to just plain `transform.position`

here is the refined code:

```
public Vector3 playerPosR;
public float paddleSpeed = 1F;
public float yClamp; // make sure it's not 0 in the inspector!

// Update is alled once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        float yPos = transform.position.y + (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * paddleSpeed);
        playerPosR = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Mathf.Clamp(yPos, -yClamp, yClamp), 0);
        transform.position = playerPosR;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a ton!